# Internet Explorer and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, protected-mode

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data:{
        SiteLinki: $('#duvarSite').html(),
        duvarIcerik: $.trim($('#share').val().replace(/\n/g,'<br />\n')),
        durum: 'paylas'
    },
    success: function(sonuc){
        verileriGetir(0);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus)
    }
});
```

It simply sends the form to the ajax.php and adds the database. It then displays the div of the page.

My problem is that this code does not work at all in Internet Explorer with protected mode turned on. It fails on the "success" portion where it is just not processed. It acts like it is completely ignored.

I have even put just an alert in the success portion and it never reaches it.

Is there something I have to do to make this work in protected mode or is there a way to detect if the browser is in protected mode? I don't have a problem with this in any other browser but IE.

Thanks
Ferhat

Comment: What version of Int***et Exp***er ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It'll be IE7 or 8 as they're the only versions with 'Protected Mode'

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Source of the problem utf-8 with Internet Explorer.

Solution to: Apache httpd.conf configuration file to add the line:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```